# Estimating relative risk/benefit with censored data in a retrospective study

Tags: survival, censoring

### Situation

Three years ago, my school district started a program where some of the at-risk students in grades 6-12 would receive an "intervention" to help them graduate instead of dropping out of school.  The district has collected the following data for the at-risk students:

```
                  Dropped out   Still in school   Graduated
Intervention    |           37 |            145 |        43 
No intervention |           78 |            112 |         6
```

The district wants to know how much the intervention increases a student's likelihood of graduating; in other words, the relative benefit of doing the intervention for the at-risk students.

### Statistics Question

I don't think I can do a "competing risks" model because I don't have the time between the intervention and graduation/dropping out for each student; I could go back through the case files and get those data if a competing risks model is the best way to determine the answer.  I could easily calculate a relative risk (or in this case benefit) by ignoring the "still in school" students, but leaving out ~60% of my data doesn't seem beneficial.  I could calculate the relative risk from pseudo-counts that assume the "still in school" kids will end up eventually dropping out or graduating in the same proportion that has already been observed, but that seems like it's just answering the question by assuming the thing that the question was supposed to answer.  What's the best thing to do here?